# wine error when trying to run a portable version of Adobe Illustrator

Tags: 18.04, wine, adobe, winetricks

few day ago i downloaded `Photoshop Portable` , it was a `.exe` file , but i can run it with wine and it works like a charm .
but now when i downloaded a Adobe Illustrator Portable version . wine gives me the bellow errors

```
arash@super:~/Programs/Illustrator-Portable$ wine IllustratorPortable.exe
reg: Invalid syntax. Type "REG IMPORT /?" for help.
002d:err:module:import_dll Library VCRUNTIME140_1.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\arash\\Programs\\Illustrator-Portable\\App\\Ai\\Support Files\\Contents\\Windows\\ahclient.dll") not found
002d:err:module:import_dll Library ahclient.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\arash\\Programs\\Illustrator-Portable\\App\\Ai\\Support Files\\Contents\\Windows\\Illustrator.exe") not found
002d:err:module:LdrInitializeThunk Importing dlls for L"Z:\\home\\arash\\Programs\\Illustrator-Portable\\App\\Ai\\Support Files\\Contents\\Windows\\Illustrator.exe" failed, status c0000135
```

> anyone knows what is my problem ??
>   please help

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and fixed it with PlayOnLinux. I installed it by terminal and then I had to create a new virtual drive and install amtlib for Adobe programs. Then you can run Photoshop CS6 and Illustrator CC.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAoOv.png)

I couldn't run Illustrator CS6, but the CC version is enought for me.